# "cannot find a complete toolset"error in vcpkg

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, installation, header, vcpkg

the following error occurred when I tried to install crypto++, a header I did not have and wanted to install using vcpkg. I use visual studio code with a g++ compiler on a windows 10 OS and use English as the main language on my device as well as vscode(apparently, english had to be installed to use vcpkg, and I felt the need to express this).

```
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    cryptopp[core]:x86-windows -> 8.2.0-2
Could not locate a complete toolset.
The following paths were examined:
```

Comment: vcpkg is a Microsoft tool, and Microsoft does not recognize mingw as anything, let alone a toolset. On Windows, a valid "toolset" is Visual C++ (or llvm-cl).

Comment: So......I won't be able to use vcpkg while I'm using g++? Is there any way around it?

Comment: I think there is some support for mingw now. However I have never used it. Related: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/triplets/community](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/triplets/community)

Comment: Don't know about vcpkg. But Mingw comes with its own package ecosystem, pacman, as well as pkg-config. There is a package [crypto++](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-crypto++) available. Having said that, on Windows, VC++ might be an easier choice.

Comment: x86-windows is the VS triplet. You need to select another triplet or create your own custom one using g++ as a compiler.